# Is there a description of HTML5 syntax that is similarly concise as the HTML 4.01 DTD?

Tags: html, dtd

I like the way the HTML4 syntax is [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html). Is there a similar description available for HTML5 (preferably HTML, not XHTML syntax)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the rules for HTML5 are fundamentally more complicated than can be expressed in a DTD. The nearest you're likely to get is [HTML5: The Markup Language Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/spec.html)

Comment: Thanks. At least it's all on one page, not too bad! Do you happen to know which parts are too complicated for a DTD? Maybe it would be possible if one neglects embedded SVG and MathML?

Comment: @wmeyer - There's all kinds of things. There was a decision early on in the creation of HTML5 that it wasn't going to be limited to DTD expressible rules (browsers have never actually matched those rules anyway). One example, DTDs don't allow rules like "The interactive element `a` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element." only that the `a` element must not be the direct child of an `a` element.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 intends to be as much backwards compatible as possible and inherits most of the syntax (albeit simplified from its predecessors).

[For a work in progress of the HTML5 spec, check this page.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html)

Comment: Imho the [Living Standard spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) is cooler `:)`

Comment: @Šime - nah, that's just what Hixie thinks today. I prefer something with a bit more stability.

Answer (score 0):

No because HTML5 is not a complete syntax as of yet.

There are good lists of available syntax though.